# Remove and re-add Class Attribute inside a <div> unordered list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

This is the answer as i was able to solve.
Wanted to change the css class="jsTree-clicked" after the button click event happened from Hyperlink1 to Hyperlink3.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        //remove Class
        $('#myJSTree').find('.jsTree-clicked').removeClass('jsTree-clicked');

        //need to do add it to List Item which has Id =3
        //check the list item which has id =3 if so add the class to it
        // It is not a button click event.         
$('#myJSTree li').each(function (i, li) {
            console.log('<li> id =' + $(li).attr('id'));
            var myIdVal = $(li).attr('id');
            if (myIdVal == 3) {
                $(this).addClass('jsTree-clicked');
            }          
        });
    });
```

```css
.jsTree-clicked { background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myJSTree">
  <ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li id="1">
      <a class="jsTree-clicked" title="Hyperlink1">HyperLink1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
      <a title="Hyperlink2">HyperLink2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
      <a title="Hyperlink3">HyperLink3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When the Hyperlink is clicked the JsTree adds a class="jsTree-clicked" . When you navigate to a different node it will remove and re-add the same class to the navigated node.

Expected

I want a function to remove [class="jsTree-clicked"] for the given List Item based on  ID inside the div.
AND
Re-add [class="jsTree-clicked"] to any ListItem by passing the Key i.e ID .

I hope I was able to explain my problem.
Thank you

My JSTree is a third party open source.

Comment: Tell me what is missing ? At least it will help me analyze the issue better. Rather than giving me a negative remark.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by validation error ?

Comment: These Hyperlink have Id. Imagine it is a FormId which is being passed to the backend to do some server side processing and bring show some data to the form. If there is some error like in controls like for eg (Textbox Control is empty in the form). The form will show some error. So this Validation happens before you navigate to any other Form  which is a Hyperlink. If there is Validation Error . I want the JSTree to realize as well. Which is by removing and readding the class="Js-Tree-clicked"

Comment: Lets say you are in Hyperlink1 and Clicked Hyperlink2 . First , it should save all the controls(textbox, textboxtable etc)  in Hyperlink1, If it has error it should show. If error is there the JSTree which we clicked to navigate i.e Hyperlink2 should not have a class="jsTree-Clicked" instead it should have in Hyperlink1 since it has validation errors and it was not processed . Hope it helps to understand my logic

Comment: So where are you checking that error ? are you having any function for that ?

Comment: That happens in the backend as we have our own validation message for each controls in the form

Comment: Have you got any javascript of what you have tried so far? Don't give us a specification and expect us to write the code for you. That's not how StackOverflow works, it's not a free code writing service. Write some code and ask some questions in regard to how your code is not working to your expectations.

Comment: My apologies, i have added my code.

Comment: Solved . Did it my way . Thank you all .

Comment: @DivyanshiMishra Please don't use the edit function to add answers to questions. Questions should _only_ contain the questions. If you have an answer, add it as an answer. Keep an eye on your [previously suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14996241/divyanshi-mishra?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). 6 out of your 10 suggested edits have been rejected. Two more _should_ have been rejected but got approved and the one that is pending also adds an answer to the question and thus should be rejected. Please don't misuse this feature.

Comment: @Ivar am not misusing any thing please don't  create issue for these thing

Comment: @DivyanshiMishra You _are_ misusing it by editing answers into other posts. That is a misuse of the edit feature. The question itself should never contain the answer. Please stop doing that.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks,  Please Don't do that I know... what i should do

Comment: @DivyanshiMishra Suggesting edits is fine, but keep the original intent of the original poster in mind. Don't add your own answers to posts. If you want to correct typo's in the text or properly format code that already exists in the post, then please do. If you want to add an answer, then add it as an answer in the answer box below the questions. Don't edit it. If the question is closed, then either add a comment or leave it be.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful to you?

```js
$(function () { $('#myJSTree').jstree(); });

const toggle = (e) => {
    if (+$("#test").val()>=10 ) {
      e.target.classList.remove("jstree-clicked");
      console.log("You entered an invalid number.")
    }
    console.log(e.target)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />


<div id="myJSTree">
        <ul>
          <li id="1">
            <a title="Hyperlink1" onclick="toggle(event)">HyperLink1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="2">
            <a title="Hyperlink2">HyperLink2</a>
          </li>
          <li id="3">
            <a title="Hyperlink3">HyperLink3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" value="3" id="test"> &lt; 10
```

I have simply included a rudimentary `toggle()` function to demonstrate the point of removing and ading the class name "jsTree-clicked". Please note that JStree assigns other classes to the node dynamically that should be kept there.

It appears to me as if the class `jstree-clicked` (not: `jsTree-clicked`) is set by JSTree *after* an element was clicked. You might have to play aroud with this further to get what you want.

The following might be more what you want. It will "link" to the given `href` only when the predefined test criteria in `checkinput()` is met:

```js
$(function () { $('#myJSTree').jstree(); });

const checkinput = (e) => {
    if (+$("#test").val()>=10 ) {
      console.log("You entered an invalid number.")
    } else document.location.href=e.target.href;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />


<div id="myJSTree">
        <ul>
          <li id="1">
            <a title="Hyperlink1" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1" onclick="checkinput(event)">HyperLink1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="2">
            <a title="Hyperlink2" href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2">HyperLink2</a>
          </li>
          <li id="3">
            <a title="Hyperlink3">HyperLink3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" value="3" id="test"> &lt; 10<br>
HyperLink1 will link to the page "user1" if the input is valid, <br>otherwise an eror will be shown in the console.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.nav-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myJSTree">
  <ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li id="1">
      <a title="Hyperlink1">HyperLink1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
      <a title="Hyperlink2">HyperLink2</a>
    </li>
    <li id="3">
      <a title="Hyperlink3">HyperLink3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```